# Python csvreader separate lines

Tags: python, loops, csv

I am using the csv module for Python. I have had a good look at the [CSV File Reading and Writing guide](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#). I want to write a loop that runs through each row in the CSV file and assigns each row do a different variable. Does anyone have any ideas on this?

I am aware that there is a `.next()` and `.line_num`, I didn't think that these would be suitable in this case although I might be wrong.

Currently I have the following code, which print out the whole CSV file:

```
print_csv = csv.reader(open(csv_name, 'rb'), delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
for row in print_csv:
    print ', '.join(row)
```

[**EDIT**]

I am now aware, from this question thread, that the best way to do this will depend on what the first line is going to be used for.

What I want to do with the first line of the CSV file is to check whether it is in the correct format. This would involve:

- checking to see whether it has the expected number of columns
- checking to see whether the column headers have the correct name
- checking to see whether to columns are in the correct order.

Comment: Why do you want to generate x vars for x lines? Isn't a list fitting to store the lines?

Comment: @oleiade I want to, for example, check that the top line in the CSV file is in the correct format. I thought that the best way to do this would be to separate out the lines into different variables.

Comment: Well you could perfectly insert every line in a list, or a dict, and then acces each lines independently using their index in it, couldn't you? :)

With the problem you describe, you perfectly could do my_check_function(my_lines_list[0]) :-)

Comment: @oleiade That does sound like a more intelligent approach. I'll look into looping through and adding to a list instead.

Comment: @joaquin thanks for the advice here. I have edited my first question to explain what I will be using the first line for. I hope I have provided sufficient information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.- Fast Answer**

Instead of setting different independent variables you could do:

```
mydict = {}
for idx, item in enumerate(reader):
    mydict['var%i' %idx] = item
```

then you call your var like:

```
mydict['var0']
```

Or still shorter in py3k:

```
mydict = {'var%i' %idx : item for idx, item in enumerate(reader)}
```

***But this doesnt have much sense applied this way***

As a commenter said this is not different than doing directly:

```
mylist = list(reader)
```

and then

```
mylist[0] # instead of 'var0'
```

and this option is much better.
The dictionary strategy is best suited when you extract the dictionary key from the very same reader line. For example, if it were at pos pos 0,:

```
mydict = {item[0] : item for item in reader}
```

---

**2.- The Proper Answer**

But if what you want is simply to check the format of the first line (maybe to calculate the space you need for printing), the method could be:

```
line = reader.next()
like_this = check_how_is_my(line)
if like_this == 'something_long':
    spaces = 23
else:
    spaces = 0

while True:
    try:
        print_with_spaces(line, spaces)
        reader.next()
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am going to have a go with this and also with using a list instead of separating each line out into a separate variable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can obviously do:

```
var1 = reader.next()
var2 = reader.next()
var3 = reader.next()
var4 = reader.next()
var5 = reader.next()
```

or any variation thereof. This is not my favorite coding style, but it works.